# spring validation rejectvalue

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I need to validate a field1 and throw a multiple error message based some 4 to 5 constraints.

```
    @Controller
    public class MyController {

        @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "myPage.html")
        public void myHandler(MyForm myForm, BindingResult result,@ valid 
        ModelAttribute("fields") Fields fields) {

          if(somethingtotrue){
                result.rejectValue(field1, desc, "field1 not valid");
          }else if(aboveIffalse){
          result.rejectValue(field1, desc, "field1 length  not valid");
          }else if(aboveiffalse){
          result.rejectValue(field1, desc, "field1 does not conatin special 
               char  valid");
          }else{
            result.rejectValue(field1, desc, "field1 not valid");
          }


        }
    }
```

data class field1 to be validated

```
        public class Fields{
                private String field1;
                private String field2;
                private String field3;
                private String field4;
                //getters and setters
        }
```

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: Is It a good approach to do

Comment: yes it is..if you want validation based on fields.